# How to build my client correctly when using docker compose?

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

After a week or so of reading Ive been experimenting with docker compose.

I have a docker compose file:

```
version: "3.8"

x-common-variables: &common-variables
  MYSQL_USER: root
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: MyPassWord
  MYSQL_DATABASE: wedding
  MYSQL_HOST_IP: 127.0.0.1
  REACT_APP_SERVER_PORT: 4000

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      <<: *common-variables
      MYSQL_HOST: localhost
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - 3307:3307
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /wedding_Script2.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/wedding_Script2.sql
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
    links:
      - mysql:mysql
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    restart: always
  server:
    build: ./weddingApp-Be
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    expose:
      - 4000
    environment:
      <<: *common-variables
      MYSQL_HOST_IP: mysql
      NODE_PATH: src
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    volumes:
      - ./weddingApp-Be/src:/server
    links:
      - mysql
    command: npm run dev
  client:
    build: ./weddingApp-Fe
    image: nginx:alpine
    environment:
      <<: *common-variables
      NODE_PATH: src
    expose:
      - 3000
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./weddingApp-Fe/src:/index
    links:
      - server
    command: nginx, -g, daemon off
```

My project structure:

[image]

inside of weddingApp-Fe my dockerFile:

```
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.0.1 -g --silent
COPY . /app
RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:1.16.0-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

When i do docker compose build:

```
mysql uses an image, skipping
phpmyadmin uses an image, skipping
Building server
Step 1/8 : FROM node:10-alpine
 ---> 8e473595b853
Step 2/8 : RUN mkdir -p /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 19b56a37f612
Step 3/8 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8dce08d04982
Step 4/8 : COPY package.json /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e5efea9d7cd2
Step 5/8 : COPY yarn.lock /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 94ed16d1b60f
Step 6/8 : COPY . /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 57942181ca20
Step 7/8 : RUN npm install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cc6cf02a698f
Step 8/8 : CMD ["npm", "run dev"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 043145db7a94

Successfully built 043145db7a94
Successfully tagged weddingapp_server:latest
Building client
Step 1/12 : FROM node:12.2.0-alpine as build
 ---> f391dabf9dce
Step 2/12 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 33e6357adf78
Step 3/12 : ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 90bef54edec6
Step 4/12 : COPY package.json /app/package.json
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 92f7b7643519
Step 5/12 : RUN npm install --silent
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 912d5018ac08
Step 6/12 : RUN npm install react-scripts@3.0.1 -g --silent
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bec736fe9b8f
Step 7/12 : COPY . /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 29232568be7d
Step 8/12 : RUN npm run build
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 59219cc1e335

Step 9/12 : FROM nginx:1.16.0-alpine
 ---> ef04b00b089d
Step 10/12 : COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a5be9b459a1b
Step 11/12 : EXPOSE 3000
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 684c6b70aed5
Step 12/12 : CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c38b886354d6

Successfully built c38b886354d6
Successfully tagged nginx:alpine
```

> Problem:

After this I do `docker compose up`

and thats when I get the following error:

```
Removing weddingapp_client_1
weddingapp_mysql_1 is up-to-date
weddingapp_phpmyadmin_1 is up-to-date
weddingapp_server_1 is up-to-date
Recreating 5b9004354493_weddingapp_client_1 ... error

ERROR: for 5b9004354493_weddingapp_client_1  Cannot start service client: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"nginx,\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

ERROR: for client  Cannot start service client: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"nginx,\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

I figure its a problem with my nginx but I dont know what.

EDIT:

If i would change to `npm start`

at the bottom of the docker-compose then I get

> ERROR: for weddingapp_client_1  Cannot start service client: OCI
> runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container
> process caused "exec: "npm": executable file not found in $PATH":
> unknown
>
> ERROR: for client  Cannot start service client: OCI runtime create
> failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused
> "exec: "npm": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Comment: Are you sure you need `image: nginx:alpine` in the client app? I'm asking because you're already telling docker compose which image to base the container on with the `build` directive.

Comment: Im not sure at all. It was something I tried in order to get this working. Didn't help

Comment: Remove it and rebuild all the images, I think it might help.

Comment: It did not help. If i however remove the command in the bottom " command: nginx, -g, daemon off" then it works but it never starts the client.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't understand from the first answer. Can you add `depends_on: server` if that's what the `client` depends on?

Comment: Well its linked with the sever which is the weddingApp-Be but I would not say that it depends on it. Should be able to run without it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're telling Compose to override the command with something that doesn't make sense:

```
command: nginx, -g, daemon off
```

This has the same effect as running that command at the command line: the comma is interpreted as part of the command.

You don't actually need this option, since the Dockerfile has

```
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

which is what you want it to do.

You can similarly delete `expose:` and `links:` (not useful in present-day Docker networking) and `volumes:` (because the code is already in your image).  If you are `build:` your own image, you do not also want `image:` naming a public Docker Hub image (your locally-built image will overwrite that one and you'll have confusing results), and the database address is probably not 127.0.0.1 ("this container").  You can probably successfully trim that part of the `docker-compose.yml` file down to

```
client:
  build: ./weddingApp-Fe
  environment:
    MYSQL_USER: root
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: MyPassWord
    MYSQL_DATABASE: wedding
    MYSQL_HOST_IP: mysql
  ports:
    - 3000:3000
```

(If you really wanted to override the command in the Dockerfile, YAML list syntax `command: [nginx, -g, 'daemon off;']` is what you'd need here, but using the default command from the Dockerfile is better.)

Comment: After this I am creating two compose files. One for dev and one for prod. I think I had this  mixed up. You adress a db issue thatI havent figured out how to do correctly and perhaps you can give some advice. In my server app I connect to mysql datbase localy and the host ip on my machine is then 127.0.0.1 but when building this in dev/prod how can I make sure I get the right host? Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

The Dockerfile for your client app is specifying `node:12.2.0-alpine` as the base image which does not include `nginx`. You will need to install NGINX in this image in order for it to work. Even though you have `nginx:alpine` as the specified image in your docker-compose file, you have pointed docker-compose build context to `./weddingApp-Fe`. This means that docker-compose will search for a Dockerfile in that directory and use it to build your image. NGINX not being installed is also the reason it doesn't crash when you remove the `command: nginx, -g, daemon off` line from the compose file.